# S3 bucket-policy "Deny" overrides the "Allow"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-role",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*******:role/task-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-s3/ln/**"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-ipaddress",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*******:role/task-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-s3/ln/**",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "*.*.*.*/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the task role to allow all actions in the S3 bucket. But I am getting access denied error when accessing the bucket. I suspect that Deny operation blocks the access but don't know the reason why since
it should deny only if the role is not a task role.

```
 exception is""Unable to create ln/list/B001480_5060854444548_response.xml on S3",
   "loggerName": "c.v.ln.utill.S3BucketHandler", "level": "ERROR", "exception":
    "software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Access Denied
     (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 9JJ3FHFYF6TTYHFKWNZZ, 
     Extended Request ID: S+r7z2sJL2ugf1+ldkjfglskgs=)\n\ta
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of the double-star wildcard that you used in the resource specification. I'm also not sure that you can use wildcards in the IP address condition (assuming that the stars aren't just there as redactions). I'd remove the entire Condition clause to verify basic behavior.

Comment: I redacted the IP addresses and we have actual IPV4 addresses. I will remove the ** from the resource section and try it out

Comment: It is working fine with the "Allow" statement, but it is throwing the access denied when I added the below section
            "Sid": "Allow-ipaddress",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::*******:role/task-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-s3/ln/**",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "*.*.*.*/*"

Comment: Have you tried the Deny with the `NotPrincipal` but without the `Condition`? Or vice-versa? I'm also assuming that you're not using a VPC endpoint (just checked the docs on `aws:SourceIp`).

Comment: My suspicion is that it's the `NotPrincipal`: I don't have time atm to read through the docs, but I believe that IAM translates user/role/group ARNs into their internal representation. I know there are warnings about how a deleting and recreating a user will cause roles that reference that user to fail. If it works as expected when the `Deny` doesn't specify a principal, try adding a condition on [aws:PrincipalArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalarn).